# Better Timer Management?

Tags: vb.net, timer

I'm working on an IRC bot in VB.net 2012. I know I know, but it's not a botnet, lol
I wanted to ask your advise on how to manage to many timers. Right now I have a timer that rewards points at a user specified interval, a timer that autosaves those points at a user specified interval. I also have one that displays advertisements, and broadcast a collection of responses at specified intervals.

I feel like it's getting out of hand and would love to know if there is a way I could do all of these thing with a single  or at least less timers.

Please keep in mind I learn as I go and don't always understand all the terminology, but I am a quick learner if you have the patience to explain. :)

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-Main") as it has all the timers built-in to its internal schedulers. You can easily just make a bunch of LINQ-like queries based on `Observable.Interval` operators to all of your timing and you won't need to worry about a single timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course you can do them with a single timer. In fact, that is what you *should* do—timers are a limited resource, and there's hardly ever a reason for a single application to use more than one of them.

What you do is create a single timer that ticks at the most frequent interval required by all of your logic. Then, inside of that timer's `Tick` event handler, you set/check flags that indicate how much time has elapsed. Depending on which interval has expired, you perform the appropriate action and update the state of the flags. By "flags", I mean module-level variables that keep track of the various intervals you want to track—the ones you're tracking now with different timers.

It is roughly the same way that you keep track of time using a clock. You don't use separate clocks for every task you want to time, you use a single clock that ticks every second. You operate off of displacements from this tick—60 of these ticks is 1 minute, 3600 of these ticks is 1 hour, etc.

However, I strongly recommend figuring out a way to do as many of these things as possible in response to *events*, rather than at regular intervals tracked by a timer. You could, for example, reward points in response to specific user actions. This type of polling is very resource-intensive and rarely the best solution.

Comment: The bot reward points based on time spent, so I don't think there is a way around this, but I have considered your idea as being the only possible option. A couple of concerns I have with it are what problems will I run into if the program is ran 24/7 will I have time tracking variables growing to large? Also will an operation inside the timer hold it up and throw the intervals off?

Comment: @Josh You reset the tracking variables each time they roll over and you perform the action. So unless you're timing *extremely* long intervals, this won't be a problem. It'll be a while before you overflow even an `Int32`. And yes, you will lose a little bit of time. But timers aren't high-resolution timing devices anyway. The minimum possible interval is 15 ms, and that can be interrupted by your application being busy or other processes pre-empting your application. It hardly matters in practice, you won't be timing at a lower resolution than seconds anyway.

Comment: So both of my concerns are valid, yet not important? lol I understand. Do you have a quick & dirty example of how this code should look?

Comment: No example on me. Depends on how many things you want to time. Either use separate variables, or create a SortedList with all the events added to it. Each time the timer ticks, work through the list and complete the tasks that have come due. Shouldn't take too long to bang together.

Comment: To make matters more precise store the Date.Now of the last Tick Event and calculate the difference to the next Tick Event's Date.Now. This is pretty precise and is not influenced by a busy application and such.